# How should __nonzero__ be implemented using the Python C-API?

Tags: python, python-c-api

How should `__nonzero__` be implemented using the Python C-API?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to fix a bug in some Python C-API code. There a `__nonzero__` method is added to the methods table as follows:

```
static PyMethodDef PyFoo_methods[] = {
    ...
    { (char*)"__nonzero__", (PyCFunction)_Foo_nonzero, METH_KEYWORDS|METH_VARARGS, NULL },
    ...
};

PyTypeObject PyFoo_Type = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL),
    0,  
    ....
    (struct PyMethodDef*)PyFoo_methods, /* tp_methods */
    ...
};
```

However, when I test the code, `bool()` applied to a `Foo` object always returns `True`; the `_Foo_nonzero` function is never called.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type customization in C is not done through specific methods in the method struct, but by filling particular fields of the `PyTypeObject` struct. In the case of `__nonzero__`, the C equivalent is the `nb_nonzero` member of the `PyNumberMethods` struct, which is pointed to by the `tp_as_number` member in the `PyTypeObject` struct: http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#number-object-structures